# Creating an XPath using the contains() function

Tags: html, objective-c, xml, xpath

For an iOS app, I'm using an open source html parser called [Hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) to scrape some data from a web page. The two tags I'm searching for are `<td class="menugridcell">` and `<td class="menugridcell_last">`

I'm trying to create one xpath that searches for either tag.  I unsuccessfully tried using the 'contains()' function:

```
NSString *queryString = @"//td[@class=contains(., 'menugridcell')]"
```

There should be 27 nodes that match this query, but oddly I was getting 1 (not even 0). I tried several variations, but I can't seem to find the right syntax.

For reference, here is how I searched for them separately

`NSString *queryString = @"//td[@class='menugridcell']"`  (returns 18 nodes)

`NSString *queryString2 = @"//td[@class='menugridcell_last']"` (returns 9 nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
//td[contains(@class, 'menugridcell')]
```

Possible alternatives are using `starts-with()` as pointed by @pault. in comment :

```
//td[starts-with(@class, 'menugridcell')]
```

or using `or` to select by one of two conditions :

```
//td[@class='menugridcell' or @class='menugridcell_last']
```

Anyway, it is a bit surprising to hear that the library you're using doesn't recognize `contains()` function, because `contains()` is available since [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) spec.

Comment: Another option is `//td[starts-with(@class, 'menugridcell')]`

Comment: It doesn't seem to recognize the contains function (invalid prefix error), but the starts-with option worked fine